# org-crypt key in .init file?

Tags: gpg

I recently setup `org-crypt` to use my gpg key to encrypt headings in org-mode files. I post my .init files in a public github repo.

My question is: Is the key in `(setq org-crypt-key "xxxxxxxx")` actually my gpg secret key?

Did I just post my gpg secret key online?

I'm revoking the key, generating a new one, then encrypting that heading in my .init file just to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-crypt-key` is the GPG key identifier, normally an email address.

Your GPG secret key resides in the secret ring in your `.gnupg` directory, and is protected by your passphrase.

From the source code comments:

```
;; 2. Set the encryption key to use in the `org-crypt-key' variable,
;;    or use `M-x org-set-property' to set the property CRYPTKEY to
;;    any address in your public keyring.  The text of the entry (but
;;    not its properties or headline) will be encrypted for this user.
;;    For them to read it, the corresponding secret key must be
;;    located in the secret key ring of the account where you try to
;;    decrypt it.  This makes it possible to leave secure notes that
;;    only the intended recipient can read in a shared-org-mode-files
;;    scenario.
;;    If the key is not set, org-crypt will default to symmetric encryption.
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Juancho. For `(setq org-crypt-key )` I entered the 8 digit ID of my key instead of an email address. I'm having trouble understanding if the 8 digit number that identifies the key is "secret" or not. 

Example: `gpg --list-keys` show a line for `pub`, `uid`, and `ssb`. I used the 8 digit number shown as `ssb 4096R/XXXXXXXX`. Is this 8 digit number secret?

Comment: That is just a key identification number. There is nothing there from your private key.

Comment: Can you add an example of using `CRYPTKEY`? It doesn't seem to work for me; I have added the property both to the encrypted header and to its parent.